# Node Js and Express: Where can I find free simple projects to learn and read the code?

Tags: node.js, express

I just completed basic tutorial about Nodejs and Express.  Where can I find free simple projects to learn and read the code that will cover much of nodejs and express?

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is considered "off-topic" here and questions will usually be closed that are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sign up for [freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.com/) it's a open source project to learn fullstack Javascript (frontend, data visualization with react.js and backend with node.js and mongodb) it has free tutorials and real world projects to do. Once you complete the all projects you can work on real programming problems for non-profits to build your portfolio.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know them already, maybe these might be useful:

https://github.com/wercker/getting-started-nodejs

http://amirrajan.net/nodejs-by-example/

Other than that, I am permanently learning tons of stuff by looking at the npm packages in the node_modules folder. Especially by reading the tests.